# why does my meatloaf fall apart when I slice it?

Tags: meatloaf

My recipe:

1.5 lbs of 90/10 lean ground beef
.75 c oatmeal
.75 c chopped onion
1 extra large beaten egg
1 tbsp worchestershire sauce
3-4 chopped garlic cloves 
.5 tsp salt
.5 tsp black pepper
I bake at 350 F until thermometer reads 170 F and let it rest in pan for 10 minutes before plating and slicing but even with a super sharp knife it falls apart.

Comment: The problem is your recipe. Try adding 1.5 cups of unsalted cracker crumbs.

Comment: Instant or regular oatmeal? It needs to suck up liquids which is why I used dried bread crumbs. 20-30 minutes might be a better wait time as the loaf tends to bond more strongly with cooling.

Comment: Do you want it to be gluten-free? Gluten-free cooking has an additional challenge to it, and it takes some experimentation and getting some basic recipes you like successfully converted before getting the hang of it I think. There may be other options than oatmeal, for sure. Oatmeal, in its many forms, can be difficult to use. Wayfaring Stranger asks a good question about which type of oatmeal. There's also sorghum, arrowroot, buckwheat (careful with this one), pamela's paleo flour is pretty awesome, and a lot more flours and meals to try, each with their own properties...

Answer (score 4):

It's the oatmeal.  I suspect it is absorbing the egg and preventing it from binding the meat together.  I suggest switching to a small amount of breadcrumbs, or day old bread torn into very small pieces if you like a little more texture.